# Twitter app for iPad to show new tweets in a badge without opening the app

Tags: ipad, ios-appstore, twitter

I'm struggling with something simple so I'd appreciate your help.

I'm looking for a Twitter app for my iPad to do the following:

1. Let me tweet (obviously)
2. Show a badge with a number on the app icon if someone tweets to me (by using @mytwittername) or if someone direct-messages me, etc. In other words, the app should do it without me opening it. Pretty much what the Mail app does. This last condition is important as all the Twitter apps that I came across so far don't seen to do it (including Twitter's own app and Twitterific.)

Is there an app that can do this?

Comment: Isn't tweetbot what you're searching for than? Caution: tweetbot is a paid app

Comment: @Jules: I checked and the iPad version had such bad reviews. But if you say that it does what I need, I'm OK about paying $3 for it?

Comment: I'm not sure if it does what you need, i think it does. Trybsearching for some videos about it or so, maybe you ser badge icons in it. Or contact the developer

Comment: @Jules: OK. Good point. Just shot a message to Tweetbot people. Let's see if they get back to me.